# Call more than one javascript functions from c# OnClick

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have landed on this bit of code to call a javascript function from c# successfully, but I can only seem to use it once per c# method. How can I call more than one function in a method? I'm sort of new to C#.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "firstEvent(event)", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "secondEvent(event)", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got into a similar issue when working with Blazor Webassembly. The solution i used was awaiting every call.

If the script manager doesn't allow awaiting them directly, try:

```
protected async void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "firstEvent(event)", true));
    await Task.Run(() => ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "secondEvent(event)", true));
}
```

It could happen because the script manager can't support multiple calls at once, so it might be ignoring the 2nd call. At least, this is what happened to me.

Comment: That would be a surprise? That only adds js to the page. When the web page travels back to client side browser, the page is displayed, and your changed HTML along with that js script is then processed by the browser.  Register script don't really run things as oppsed to just adding to the existing web page before it travels back down to the client side. That's when the web page with your html and the extra js code is both rendered, and then the js is run. You not running anything more here then setting a text box that becomes part of the page markup, and so does adding script to the page.

Comment: Now, given your case is web assembly and blazer? I don't think that applies here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal That's why i said it's a similar issue and that it could be a concurrency problem, as it basically means calling resources from a different language.

Comment: See my answer below - I explain the issue, and how to fix this for a regular asp.net web page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your problem is two fold.

Remember, all that command does is add some script to the web page, sends it down to client side.

So, there are two ways to do this. Simple put both function calls into one, like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(This.Page, Page.GetType,
  "text", "test1();test2();", True)
```

And you can also do this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(This.Page, Page.GetType, "text", "test1();", True)
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "text2", "test2();", True)
```

Note how we give a new "key" name - if you don't do this, then the 2nd one is overwriting the next one.

However, EVEN this will NOT work:

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType, "text", "test1()", True)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "text2", "test2()", True)
```

note the missing ";" after the function

so

```
 Test1()   - only works for one
 Test1();  - will work if you add more
```

So, if you eave out the trailing ";", then the script gets injected as

```
Test1()Test2()
```

And you need

```
Test1();Test2();
```

So, either put both calls in the one script inject like

```
Test1();Test2();
```

Or with your two script inject calls?

Then you NEED both a different key name, and ALSO must add the trailing ";" so that they are seen as separate js function calls.